# How to add timezone with my timestamp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have timezone as string (like **"(GMT+00:00) UTC", "(GMT+05:30) Chennai"** and so on.). Also I have timestamp like **Mon, 01 Aug 2016 17:00:00 UTC +00:00**. I need to change timestamp time based on timezone. Also timezone in the timestamp should not be changed. Im using rails 4.0.0. On every try it tells strings cannot be converted. Could anyone please help on this.

Comment: Were do the time zone strong come from? Perhaps you can use the list of names that are provided by ActiveSupport::TimeZone instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to retrieve the time zone from your string:

```
tz_as_string = "(GMT+05:30) Chennai"
tz_name = tz_as_string[/(?<=\) ).*/] # ⇒ "Chennai"
tz_timezone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING[tz_name] #⇒ "Asia/Kolkata"
```

and, finally:

```
tz = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new tz_timezone
#⇒  #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x000000107a91c0 @name="Asia/Kolkata", ...
Time.parse('Mon, 01 Aug 2016 17:00:00 UTC +00:00').in_time_zone tz
#⇒ Mon, 01 Aug 2016 22:30:00 IST +05:30
```